# Laravel корзина с использованием БД

Tags: mysql, laravel

Я делаю одну игру, хочу сделать такую систему:

- Есть различные товары (Parts table)
- Есть несколько магазинов (Shops table)
- Один и тот же товар могу продавать разные продавцы (shop_part table + поле count)

То есть, один и тот же товар можно купить у нескольких продавцов. И я хочу сделать корзину для пользователей. Не через сессии, а через бд, чтобы к корзине был доступ с нескольких устройств.

Как лучше всего это реализовать?

Я думал сделать таблицу `carts`, где будут поля `id, user_id, shop_part_id, count`. Но как тогда с помощью laravel отношений получить доступ к товару конкретного продавца через модель пользователя?

Answer (score 1):

Таблица `carts` должна быть `id, buyer_id, product_id, count` в таблица
`Parts table` должно быть поле на продавца `created_by`, таблице `Shops table` должна быть таблица магазинов с полями которые нужны для магазина, а также еще должна быть таблица `Shop to products` которая связывает нужный товар с нужным магазином many-to-many.

Таким образом через заказ можно получить хоть пользователя, хоть товар, хоть магазин в котором был этот товар

Comment: Не совсем понял про Parts table. Там не может быть поля `created_by`, тк один товар может продаваться у нескольких продавцов (many to many). Но потом вы говорите про `Shop to products` - это как раз many to many. В чем прикол?

Comment: `users `-> `carts `<- `part_shop `<- (`parts` + `shops`) - вот так я это представляю - `carts` и `part_shop` - many to many

Comment: @Colorkat Значит нужно создать еще одну таблицу many-to-many в которой будет связь продавца и продукта, в таблицу заказов добавить seller_id потому как через связь ты не сможешь понять у какого конкретно продавца был куплен товар

Comment: А мне казалось, что в laravel можно через pivot таблицу работать с many to many. Там есть polymorph связи, надо почитать